# Laravel many to many relationship

Tags: laravel

I'm new to laravel .. currently developing web application with this structure:
**Tables**
- users (id, name, email, phone)
- schools (id, name, email, phone, user_id->'foreign')
- players (id, name, email, phone, user_id->'foreign', school_id->'foreign')
- officers (id, name, email, phone, user_id->'foreign', school_id->'foreign')
- events (id, name, date, location, status'active-archived-canceld', notes)
 
- the user has to create only one school with multi players and officers.

I have built relations between users, schools, players, officers ...

**But the problem is**
- school can register to many events with different list of players every time.
in events view, I'm showing all events with check box for schools to participate in events.

How to make relation between schools & events where the school can register once to an event & add custom players list from players attached to it?
& how save this custom list of players?

Answer (score 0):

I think your database structure is not well-designed. I would've done it this way:

1. Delete the `Players` and `Officers` table. they are just users with differenet roles! so add a `type`(or a better choice: `Role`) column to your users table to set the type of users( for example set 1 for players , 2 for officers , 3 for admin ,...)
2. create a team table as pivot with this structure:

   ```
   team(id , school_id , user_id)
   ```

now you have teams and you can specify which school it is for and which players are in it.

3. add event_teams table

   ```
    events_teams(id , team_id , event_id)
   ```

now different schools with different teams can be added to this table.

Comment: i solved it ,, was the events table .. it's reserved for laravel